# Appending text on a character interval

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to write a program where the participant communicates with the program (I/O) via a console. Trick is, the console is part of a GUI, because I need the program to run off of a executable jar file. I append text with a scrollable text field, like so

```
textArea.append(printChar);
```

I give the method a `String` to work with, and it uses a nested for loop to take it, char by char, and append each Char (using `string.substring()`).

My problem is that it freezes up the entire time its supposed to be printing, then just displays it all. I don't know why, because I tested it using `System.out.print`, and it worked exactly as I wanted. So something is different about appending and printing. Any ideas?

Also, I am using `Thread.Sleep(100)` for my wait time.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (!preforming){

        preforming = true;
        String input = textField.getText();   //Text from Input
        textArea.append(dungeon.name + ": " + input + newline);     //Add "text" to bottom of console
        String[] output = dungeon.action(input);


        //print everything in array output, char by char, with 2-3 seconds after each
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++){
            String printThis = output[i];

            if (printThis.length() > 0){
                for (int j = 0; j < printThis.length(); j++){
                    String printChar = printThis.substring(j, j+1);
                    textArea.append(printChar);
                    //System.out.print(printChar);
                    try{  
                        Thread.sleep(5);    
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            System.out.print("Error ");
                    }
                     /*try { //useless
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     }*/
                }
            }
             textArea.append("" + newline); 
        }


        //cleaning up input bar
        textField.setText("");
        textField.selectAll();
        //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
        //was a selection in the text area.
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
        preforming = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add keywords to explain what UI you are using.  Is this Android?

Comment: Also, adding characters to a GUI textArea widget may not be very fast because the textArea may be doing a lot of non-obvious things as it receives the input like setting fonts and colors etc. Do you have to loop through the string to print it one character at a time? Why not just append the whole string?

Comment: Do not call `sleep` in `actionPerformed`. `actionPerformed` gets called on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), which is also responsible for rendering. Calling `sleep` on the Event Dispatch Thread will freeze your GUI, since it will prevent the EDT from processing graphics. You can create a regular `java.util.Timer` which handles calculations, then call `appendText` within an `invokeLater` to allow `appendText` to properly execute on the EDT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited my answer as you are showing more of your codes. Since, there is an outer loop in your code, I just included it inside the run method of `timer` in this new edit. And also I don't have the code for the `dungeon` so I just temporarily replace it with constant values so the program can run in my test.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
    timer.schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if (!preforming){
                preforming = true;
                String newline = "\n";
                String dungeonName = "Star Light";


                String input = textField.getText();   //Text from Input
                textArea.append(dungeonName + ": " + input + newline);     //Add "text" to bottom of console
                String[] output = {
                    "Twinkle twinkle little star.",
                    "How I wonder what you are.",
                    "Up above the world so high."
                };


                //print everything in array output, char by char, with 2-3 seconds after each
                for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++){
                    String printThis = output[i];

                    if (printThis.length() > 0){
                        for (int j = 0; j < printThis.length(); j++){
                            String printChar = printThis.substring(j, j+1);
                            textArea.append(printChar);
                            //System.out.print(printChar);
                            try{
                                Thread.sleep(25);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                System.out.print("Error ");
                            }
                 /*try { //useless
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }*/
                        }
                    }
                    textArea.append("" + newline);
                }


                //cleaning up input bar
                textField.setText("");
                textField.selectAll();
                //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
                //was a selection in the text area.
                textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
                preforming = false;
            }
        }
    }, 1);
}
```

Comment: This definetly works to add char by char... but for some reason often makes the first part of printThis into total gibberish as it prints. this is the same if I print using this to the console. any reason why? I have updated my origonal code to include the entire method

Comment: I updated my answer to include the outer loop inside the `timer`. The run method of the `timer` is a separate thread. So if it is placed inside a loop then each iteration is a separate  process. The processes may cross each other on updating the `textArea`. So putting the whole codes inside the timer, ensures that the updates to the `textArea` is in sequence.

Comment: Added, changed variables a bit, perfect implementation. Thank you so much! One more question; I can't seem to figure out what }; or ), 1);  do (and why they are used instead of just a }. If you could clear that up for me, that would be awesome! Also, kudos to vince emigh for pointing out the event dispatch thread.

Comment: @PHS00 the `}, 1);` in the code is just a closing brace and a closing parenthesis of `TimerTask` and `timer.schedule`. It's the last part of `timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){}, 1);`.

Comment: @PHS00 And also the `};` in code is the closing brace of array initialization. It's the last part of `String[] output = { };` It's one of the syntaxes to initialize an array.